How to extract all object from image
I need to extract all objects from image using OpenCV. Code works normal for images where objects locate separate from each other. But when objects are close to each other I have problems
Normal example:

Bad example:

In bad example objects are combined, but I need them separated for further processing. I know that normal example also have some troubles, but they aren't critical.
This is code I'm using:
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::CommandLineParser parser(
        argc, argv, "{@input | | input image}");
    cv::Mat src =
        cv::imread(cv::samples::findFile(parser.get<cv::String>("@input")),
                   cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    if (src.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open or find the image!\n" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <Input image>" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(src, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::Mat filtred;
    cv::bilateralFilter(gray, filtred, 11, 17, 17);

    cv::Mat canny;
    cv::Canny(filtred, canny, 40., 120.);
    cv::imshow("canny", canny);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    cv::Mat kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(2, 2));
    cv::Mat closed;
    cv::morphologyEx(canny, closed, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, kernel);

    cv::imshow("morph", closed);

    std::vector<contour> contours;
    cv::findContours(closed, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    cv::Mat with_contours;
    src.copyTo(with_contours);

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        if (cv::contourArea(contours[i]) > 100.)
        {
            cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);
            cv::rectangle(with_contours,
                          rect,
                          cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0),
                          2);
        }

    imshow("contours", with_contours);


This is not a trivial problem. Canny is certainly not useful towards a solution. What is an object? How do you (geometrically) define an object? When you look at the image, you identify what fruit you're looking at, and your experience tells you where one piece ends and another starts. You have a model of what the fruit looks like. I don't think you can solve this problem without such a model. I'm not saying this needs deep learning, but you do need a model (a mathematical description of what individual pieces of fruit looks like) to solve this.

if the background is always white (or a bland color), i also don't think there is a need for DL.

Maybe your approach is good solution, but I think it's not for me. Also because I'm new to OpenCV I don't know how to realize this for now. I have task that I need to find similar objects on image (for example 2 apples, 3 strawberries and etc), so I decided to take pictures with fruits, but it can be anything. I decided to extract objects from image for finding similar objects by matchTemplate. Maybe you have another idea for solving this problem?
